# JMS message, unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, sax

I have an unexplainable problem that just cropped up.  In production a RedHat webserver OS was updated/patched and when it restarted, our spring jms application suddenly stopped working.  No code has changed.

Here is the error message :

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:318)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
        at ca.mycompany.middleware.data.serializer.JAXBSerializer.serialize(JAXBSerializer.java:30)

...

 Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:248)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:137)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
        ... 15 more
```

I don't understand what the problem is ?

UPDATE:

I found the problem.  When I started stepping through the code, I found that the real root of the problem was that my application was being blocked by this exception  :

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

I have a work-around, but I'm trying to figure out what changed to block the way I used to call the webservice.

Comment: From what version of RH did you upgrade? to/from?

Comment: Which packages have been upgraded? Especially the packages which are related to the stack you use (jboss, tomcat, lib*java*, JDK).

Comment: I discovered this is the real exception :javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Answer (score 0):

So, was your java version upgraded?
It seems like in this area of your code:

`at ca.mycompany.middleware.data.serializer.JAXBSerializer.serialize(JAXBSerializer.java:30)`

you're trying to JAXB Serialize a string.  This isn't allowed.  I wouldn't be surprised if it was a bug in older versions.